# How to collect output from a Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stanford-nlp, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a python process that reads some input, processes it and prints out the result. The processing is done by a subprocess (Stanford's NER), for ilustration I will use 'cat'. I don't know exactly how much output NER will give, so I use run a separate thread to collect it all and print it out. The following example illustrates.

```
import sys
import threading
import subprocess

#   start my subprocess
cat = subprocess.Popen(
    ['cat'],
    shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=None)


def subproc_cat():
    """ Reads the subprocess output and prints out """
    while True:
        line = cat.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print("CAT PROC: %s" % line.decode('UTF-8'))

#   a daemon that runs the above function
th = threading.Thread(target=subproc_cat)
th.setDaemon(True)
th.start()

#   the main thread reads from stdin and feeds the subprocess
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("MAIN PROC: %s" % line)
    if not line:
        break
    cat.stdin.write(bytes(line.strip() + "\n", 'UTF-8'))
    cat.stdin.flush()
```

This seems to work well when I enter text with the keyboard. However, if I try to pipe input into my script (cat file.txt | python3 my_script.py), a racing condition seems to occur. Sometimes I get proper output, sometimes not, sometimes it locks down. Any help would be appreciated!

I am runing Ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4.0. The solution should be platform-independant.

Comment: Someone once told me double pipe is problematic, without providing a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `th.join()` at the end otherwise you may kill the thread prematurely before it has processed all the output when the main thread exits: daemon threads do not survive the main thread (or remove `th.setDaemon(True)` instead of `th.join()`).

Comment: Doh, so simple, and I missed it. Thanks! :D
I will however keep the other thread a daemon, but I will sleep the main thread after the main loop, to give the other thread time to output the results.

Comment: @FlorijanStamenković time.sleep() is the wrong thing here. You could pass the `timeout` parameter to `th.join()` if the child process may stuck.

Comment: J.F., thanks for your comment. I am not sure I understand how join() will help. Here is why:

Comment: @FlorijanStamenković `th.join()` won't return until the thread is done or the timeout happens. Unlike `time.sleep()` that can sleep both too little and too much.

Comment: J.F. I failed to finish my previous comment. Sorry about that.

The reason why waiting for the daemon thread seems pointless is because it's an infinite loop polling output from a separate process. It is never done. In that sense it seems that join() with timeout or sleep() is really the same thing.

In the end I ditched all the multithreading and wrote a simple Java program that handles Stanford's NER so that I can control that it gives one line of output per one line of input. When that is the case, I can synchronise my Python process and external processes and don't need multithreading.

Comment: If you exit prematurely; you may hang the child process (when it fills its stdout OS pipe buffer). If NER never ends; you should keep the reading thread alive.